# HDMI overscanning

Tags: hdmi, raspberrypi, 21.04, overscan

I'm using a pi4 with Ubuntu 21.04 and have it all hooked up to a TV via HDMI. The desktop is overscanned so much that icons are missing. I've tried changing the resolutions, but the same amount of overscanning persists. I also tried playing with the TV's zoom settings, which also failed to resolve the issue.

What can I do?

Comment: Update your original question with the full results of running `xrandr` and also what make/model TV or exactly what resolution/s and refresh rates does it support and what resolution are you attempting to output?

Comment: There should be a setting on your TV that will do 1:1 pixel mapping for the current source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1:1_pixel_mapping